# Subclipse only displays folder not content in Project Explorer view

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm working on a Project with a friend using Subclipse. Committing successfully works and all files and folders are shown in the SVN Repositories view. However, in the Project Explorer view only the folders are shown without the content.

How can the files in the folders be shown in the Project Explorer view?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did not commit the Eclipse project files such as .project, .classpath etc.  These are used by the JDT to configure the Java project which is what drives the Project Explorer.

Normally, the symptom of this is that you see the folders and files but they are not displayed as packages and classes.

If the Files are there and you see them in other views, then maybe there is some kind of filter applied to the view that is causing them to not show.